# Perform Delete on documents that are retrived via find statement in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

is it possible to perform a delete on "found documents"?

For example something like performs similar to below

```
var foundDoc = db.collection.find().limit(100);
foundDoc.remove();
```

Thanks.

Comment: You could find the ids then delete with the $in operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`db.collection.find().limit(100).forEach(function(doc) {
db.collection.remove({_id:doc._id});

});`